# Translating SOAP Messages from VBA to VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, vba, soap

I am trying to modify my code that I wrote in VBA (and works fine) into VB.Net.

This is the code:

```
Sub SOAP(ByVal SOAPCommand As String)


Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim sEnvlength As Integer
Dim responseText As String

Set ObjHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
sURL = "http://localhost:9002"

sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "<SOAP-ENV:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "<" & SOAPCommand & "/>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</SOAP-ENV:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

sEnvlength = Len(sEnv)

ObjHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False
ObjHttp.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Dispatcher"
ObjHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=us-ascii"
ObjHttp.SetRequestHeader "Host", "localhost:9002"
ObjHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", sEnvlength
ObjHttp.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "close"

ObjHttp.send (sEnv)

xmlDoc.LoadXML (ObjHttp.responseText)
responseText = ObjHttp.responseText

If Not (responseText = "") Then

MsgBox (responseText)

End If

End Sub
```

I know that I can't use the MSXML in VB.Net anymore, but I have not found a convenient solution yet how to modify my code so that I can use it with the rest of my project on Visual Studio.

Until now, I have this code as a macro in a separate Excel file that I call with a new Excel.Application method that opens and closes the files every time, but as it has to be repeated thousands of times (for a simulation) this does not really look like a good solution.

Does anybody have an idea how I could send my SOAP message via VB.Net?

I do have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, it is a bad idea to manipulate XML to send a message to a SOAP service. Just use the "Add Service Reference" command and make calls to the service almost as though it were just another class.

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" for details.

Note also that one should never create XML through string manipulation. The rules are just different. Always use an XML API for that. You're very lucky to be using VB.NET, which can build XML inline.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I can unfortunately not consume the Webservice as it is desribed in your link. The service does not have any WSDL file. I just send messages formatted like the one above to the service, and the service sends other messages back to a port my program is listening to. Although being a good tip, the link does not help in my situation.

Comment: Are you certain there's no WSDL? What is the service written in? That's a very rare thing. If you can't consume it normally, then at least look at "[XML Literals Overview (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)" to see the better way to create XML if you must.